# Record a video in python

Tags: python, video-recording

I try to record a video in python. Running the code below create me a .mp4 file but is is 0KB and when i open i get the error that the data is corrupted and unable to open. I tried opening with VLC, Media Player and all other toold i got on Windows 11. Also tried everything available on the internet same problem every time

```
 import cv2
    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 720)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('recording.mp4', fourcc, 30.0, (1280, 720))
recording = False

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        print('working')
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)
        if recording:
            writer.write(frame)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    elif key == ord('r'):
        recording = not recording
        print(f'recording: {recording}')

# Release the video capture and writer objects
cap.release()
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the code below won't record anything unless you press r. So if you run the code and it generates a 0Kb file it's perfectly normal.

Comment: I noticed that... My question was why is not writing any data to that file. Run it yourself and you ll see is not working

Comment: I see. I run it, I don't press r and nothing is saved because the variable recording is False. Works as expected

Comment: If u press r, wait a while and press r or q, can you OPEEEEN the video you saved? How can you be so superficial, to not even read my problem

Comment: So now that you see what i need can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a size manually, but the camera might not work at that resolution.

To solve the problem, you can manually set the resolution to 1280x720 but then instead of hardcoding the capture resultion, retrieve it from the camera

This way if the camera works at the desired resolution good, if not it will work at the default one.

```
import cv2
    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# set the camera to 1280x720
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 720)

# but here get the actual resolution
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) + 0.5)
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) + 0.5)
size = (width, height)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

# then use here the actual resolution instead of the hardcoded one
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('recording.mp4', fourcc, 30.0,(width,height)) 

recording = False

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        print('working')
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)
        if recording:
            writer.write(frame)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    elif key == ord('r'):
        recording = not recording
        print(f'recording: {recording}')

# Release the video capture and writer objects
cap.release()
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: it works, thank you

Comment: Isn't there a button for exactly that?